# @vite('resources/js/app.js') is not working with vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

`@vite('resources/js/app.js')` is not working with all installations... it is not even showing and working

pakage.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.27",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.5.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "vite": "^3.0.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.3",
        "vue": "^3.2.36",
        "vue-loader": "^17.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: check in source page whether app.js include or not

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that can be going on. Here is some really nice and recent example of getting a laravel, vue, vite project off the ground from scratch. Check it out and make sure the files on question and those imported to those files have a similar structure as yours. And the flow is similar.

https://techvblogs.com/blog/spa-authentication-laravel-9-sanctum-vue3-vite